# how to duplicate 1000 records and change their id?

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I have one problem, how I can duplicate in prisma my base data in db:

```
[
  {"id":"6a9122b2-363b-4a4f-ad26-d6c55b51baed","title":"TailwindCSS"},
  {"id":"2ea8cfb0-44a3-4c07-bdc2-31ffa135ea78","title":"Apollo GraphQL"}
]
```

I want duplicate this rows x 1000, and changed id for each records as indyvidual id.
What I shoudl to do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an npm package like [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) to generate ids and use them while inserting data.

You can generate UUID like this:

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
uuidv4(); // ⇨ '9b1deb4d-3b7d-4bad-9bdd-2b0d7b3dcb6d'
```

Considering this schema:

```
model Courses {
  id    String @id
  title String
}
```

You could insert records this way:

```js
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    const id = uuidv4();
    await prisma.courses.create({
      data: {
        id: id,
        title: 'TailwindCss',
      },
    });
  }
```

Another alternative is to define `default` in the schema file, which would allow you to automatically generate UUIDs for you.

This is how you could define default id's

```
model Courses {
  id    String @id @default(cuid())
  title String
}
```